# Mysql Pivot table / crosstab with display text

Tags: mysql

I need to show pivot table or crosstab like this, and  my code below the table.

But the result is not the same as shown in the table.

| Mach Name | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spring Assembly | Robatech | Panel Display | control | Air Leak | Cutter |
| Spring Assembly | Inverter | Sensor | Conveyor |  |  |
| Spring Assembly | No Power |  |  |  |  |

```
SELECT  machtype AS Machine_Type,
CASE WHEN priors = '5' THEN problems ELSE NULL END AS '5',
CASE WHEN priors = '4' THEN problems ELSE NULL END AS '4',
CASE WHEN priors = '3' THEN problems ELSE NULL END AS '3',
CASE WHEN priors = '2' THEN problems ELSE NULL END AS '2',
CASE WHEN priors = '1' THEN problems ELSE NULL END AS '1'
FROM priority
```

I try this code but the result is not the same in the table that I shown above.

Comment: MACH NAME is the same for all rows in your example so what's the rule for the column entries for each row?  is there a category for machine type for example? and why does mach name not appear in your query?

Comment: I already corrected from Mach Name to Machine_Type. But the expected result is not the same to the sample above

Comment: Please add sample data as text to the question.

Comment: The value of number '4' is placed on the row 4 & 5 with the same column. Value of number '3' is placed on row 6 & 7 with the same column. Value of number '2' is placed on row 8 with the same column. Value of number '1' is placed on row 9 with the same column.